# SPA on Livewire not loading js elements after 2nd page Render

Tags: php, laravel, turbolinks, laravel-livewire, livewires

My SPA based on livewire is not loading javascript events after second page rendering:
For example, two cases :

1. First page refresh in dashboard loads the charts plugin. After I render some other page and come back to dashboard, the chart does not load again.
2. I refresh the page, my menus in sidebar are collapsed. After I render some other page, they do not appear collapsed.

I'm using Turbolinks with Livewire on Laravel 8.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, for me it did not work because I put the JS code into a **window.onload function** but when I removed the function, the inner code executed twice so I placed the inner code into a **separate file** and imported it and it works. **Try putting the Charts initialization in a separate file.**

Else have a look @ this:
https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1022

Comment: Thank you so much. What worked for me was :

I put 

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {

instead of 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


Hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
    @livewireScripts
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/livewire/turbolinks@v0.1.x/dist/livewire-turbolinks.js" data-turbolinks-eval="false"></script>
</body>
```